# Qooxdoo ComboBox key/value serialization

Tags: javascript, data-binding, qooxdoo

Can someone please provide an example how to do proper serialization of data in key value pairs in qooxdoo ComboBox or VirtualComboBox?

I have this example data `[{"label":"","value":"0"},{"label":"Male","value":"m"},{"label":"Female","value":"f"}]`

And while in label I want to display the label, in the server I want to send the value.

It seems that the serializer uses the getValue() function which just returns the content of the textbox. I have an example here http://tinyurl.com/qcl7pmg but I don't know how to make it send "M" instead of "Male". Something like this example from the DemoBrowser http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#data~Form.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported a bug almost 4 years ago in days of Qooxdoo 1.x ([#5469](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5469)) about it. But it's more a lack of the feature than a bug. To bind complex data structures to forms is not a simple thing to do. It requires good understanding of Qooxdoo data-binding and a lot of practice with it. But it gives you great flexibility and automation in building `qx.ui.form.Form`s with `qx.data.controller.Form`.

The key is binding options that you set per form widget with [`qx.data.controller.Form.prototype.addBindingOptions`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/4.1.1/apiviewer/#qx.data.controller.Form~addBindingOptions). It gives control over what comes from the model to the widget and vice versa. With a little trick you can even use Qooxdoo table under `qx.data.controller.Form`.

There's a [snippet](http://tinyurl.com/p5uwonm) for binding a combo box to a form, which operates with Qooxdoo object representing list items.

```
var listData = [
  {"label": "(empty)", "value": "0"},
  {"label": "Male", "value": "m"},
  {"label": "Female", "value": "f"}
];
var listModel = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel(listData);

var formData = {'gender': listData[0]};
var formModel = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel(formData);

var form = new qx.ui.form.Form();
var formController = new qx.data.controller.Form(null, form);

var comboBox = new qx.ui.form.ComboBox();
var comboList = comboBox.getChildControl('list');
var listController = new qx.data.controller.List(listModel, comboList, 'label');

form.add(comboBox, 'Gender', null, 'gender');

var genderModelToTargetConverter = function(value, model, sourceObj, targetObj)
{
  if(value instanceof qx.core.Object)
  {
    listController.setSelection(new qx.data.Array([value]));
    return value.getLabel();
  }
  return value;
};
var genderTargetToModelConverter = function(value, model, sourceObj, targetObj)
{
  return listController.getSelection().getItem(0);
};
formController.addBindingOptions(
  'gender', 
  {'converter': genderModelToTargetConverter.bind(this)},
  {'converter': genderTargetToModelConverter.bind(this)}
);
formController.setModel(formModel);

var sendButton = new qx.ui.form.Button('Send');

this.getRoot().add(comboBox, {left: 10, top: 10});
this.getRoot().add(sendButton, {left: 10, top: 50});

sendButton.addListener('execute', function()
{
  var result = qx.util.Serializer.toNativeObject(formModel); 
  console.log(result['gender']);
}, this);
```

In practice, unlikely that it makes sense to do it all in the same class. It's fragile and complex. Basically you need to implement a sort of MVC based on Qooxdoo data layer. Then things get very clear and much simpler. As an example, here's [frontend](https://bitbucket.org/saaj/cherrypy-webapp-skeleton/src/frontend/source/class/webapp) of *cherrypy-webapp-skeleton* with such simple implementation.